# cómo hago solicitud PHP para extraer resultados de un sorteo de lotería?

Tags: php, wordpress

Estoy tratando de extraer los resultados de sorteos de una lotería, pero el `cron job` tira un informe de error, al parecer el `Script.php` tiene problemas, he tratado de repararlo usando `google bard`, pero no ha sido posible.

Aquí esta el mensaje de error:

**Cron output**

> Warning: DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in /home/u879658385/domains/loterianacionalresultadosdehoy.com/public_html/loterias/actualizar_resultados.php on line 43 Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /home/u879658385/domains/loterianacionalresultadosdehoy.com/public_html/loterias/actualizar_resultados.php on line 43 Warning: DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in /home/u879658385/domains/loterianacionalresultadosdehoy.com/public_html/loterias/actualizar_resultados.php on line 44 Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /home/u879658385/domains/loterianacionalresultadosdehoy.com/public_html/loterias/actualizar_resultados.php on line 44 Warning: DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in /home/u879658385/domains/loterianacionalresultadosdehoy.com/public_html/loterias/actualizar_resultados.php on line 45 Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/u879658385/domains/loterianacionalresultadosdehoy.com/public_html/loterias/actualizar_resultados.php on line 48 Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/u879658385/domains/loterianacionalresultadosdehoy.com/public_html/loterias/actualizar_resultados.php on line 52 Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/u879658385/domains/loterianacionalresultadosdehoy.com/public_html/loterias/actualizar_resultados.php on line 56
>
> ### Resultados de la loterÃ­a

Comment: Buenas, Elvis, bienvenido al sitio, ¿le has echado un ojo a [tour] y [ask]? ¿Puedes editar la pregunta e incluir tu código como texto formateado? Al menos todas esas líneas que te están dando error en el fichero actualizar_resultados.php. Todo parece empezar a ir mal cuando pasas más parámetros de los esperados a DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName(). Si desconocemos tu código y qué parámetros estás pasando ahí, ¿cómo quieres que te ayudemos exactamente?

Comment: Gracias, trato de poner la ruta de salida al scrip.ph . aclaro, estoy tratando de extraer los resultados de un sorteo de loterias, el script hace solicitud http a la pagina del sorteo, tengo inconvenientes con la impresión de los resultados, el cron job arroja el  error; array(0) { } string(92) "/home/u879658385/domains/loterianacionalresultadosdehoy.com/public_html/loterias/salida.html"   ,.En el archivo que he creado para recibir os resultados impresos se llama; salida.html y solo se ha impreso lo siguiente; <h2>Resultados de la lotería</h2><ul></ul>

Comment: De nada, hombre. Pero sigues sin incluir la parte de actualizar_resultados.php que te está fallando. No los números de línea, lo que has escrito en esas líneas. ¿Y cómo le pasas los datos desde ahí a salida.html?

Comment: estoy tratando de pegar el código aquí, pero excede el limite de palabras admitida por esta plataforma, puedo ponerlo en drive y dejarte el enlace para que lo veas?